# View .eml File directly in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11

is there any possibility to view a .eml file directly in IE11?
I googled a lot and tried different settings, but I only got this two behaviours:

- It asks me to open or save the .eml file
- It opens the .eml file in another window

-> What i exactly want is to open the .eml file in the same window (no new tab or anything)

**Changing the ending to .mht is not a solution for me**

Thank you for your support!